# BeautifulSoup doesn't show text in class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to parse my school's website to make a bot that gets the homework for me. The problem is that BeautifulSoup doesn't show the text I need. On the website it's like this:

```
<td class="homework">
    Paragraph 41, №2,3<br><br>
</td>
```

But in the result of my code, it shows this:

```
<td class="homework">
    <%= homework %></td>
```

Why does this happen? Why is there actual text on the website, but some weird replacement in the code?
Here is the code I'm using for this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url1 = 'https://school.karelia.ru/auth/login'
url2 = 'https://school.karelia.ru/personal-area/#diary'

payload = {
    'login_login': 'username',
    'login_password': 'password'
}

def getHW():
    with requests.session() as s:
        s.post(url1, data=payload)
        r = s.get(url2)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.prettify())

getHW()
```

Comment: The values are added by some JavaScript code in the browser, and `requests` isn't a browser. It doesn't run the JavaScript, so you only get the HTML returned by the server. You may have better luck with Selenium as it uses an actual browser.

Comment: Do you really think it is a good idea to share username and password?

Answer (score 2):

The weird `<%= homework %>` tag is replaced by javascript in the page that presumably gets the homework assignment. Either look through the page source to find where it gets the homework or use selenium, a "browser automator" that actually runs javascript.